# make VSCode snippets for a writer

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I am a writer and use VSCode as an editor. because its awesome!
but it's little bit uncomfortable on typing. like curly quotes.
So to solve problem, I make 'markdown.json file' to change smart quotes('') to curly quotes(“”) automatically.

```
"smart quotes in markdown": {
    "prefix": "\"\"",
    "body": [ "“$1”$2" ],
    "description": "to use curly quotes instead of straight quotes"
},
```

it works on txt file! (which is open by VSCode)
So happy and I try one more things...

```
    "( in markdown": {
    "prefix": "\u0028",
    "body": [ "($1)$2" ],
    "description": "to type (any word) easy"
},

"{ in markdown": {
    "prefix": "\u007B",
    "body": [ "{$1}$2" ],
    "description": "to type {any word} easy"
},

"[ in markdown": {
    "prefix": "\u005B",
    "body": [ "[$1]$2" ],
    "description": "to type [any word] easy"
},

"| in markdown": {
    "prefix": "\u007C",
    "body": [ "|$1|$2" ],
    "description": "to type |any word| easy"
},

"< in markdown": {
    "prefix": "\u003C",
    "body": [ "<$1>$2" ],
    "description": "to type <any word> easy"
},

"memo in markdown": {
    "prefix": "\u003D",
    "body": [ "=$1=$2" ],
    "description": "to use memo destinguisher instead of //"
}
```

this time it doesn't work. :( where is the problem? prefix unicode charactor number is wrong? or these special charactors are Un-usable? how can I fix this?

Comment: why do you use `\u1234` as prefix, just copy the UTF-8 unicode character

Comment: Thank you for a comment. I try "prefix": "7B". but doesn't work.
I use \u1234 because of this > [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/sql/relational-databases/json/how-for-json-escapes-special-characters-and-control-characters-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: why use `\u0028` as prefix if this is the character `(`, have you tried typing `\u0028` and see if the snippet is triggered